# Conditions for omitting type declarations in a where clause

Tags: idris

The [tutorial](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#where-clauses) section on `where` clauses gives 2 conditions for being able to omitt the type declaration of a function `f` in a `where` clause:

> - `f` appears in the right hand side of the top level definition
> - The type of `f` can be completely determined from its first application

My question is: what is the relation between these two conditions? 'and', 'or', 'mutually exclusive', does one imply the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both conditions must be met, e.g.:

```
test1 : List Int -> List Int
test1 xs = map inc xs
  where
    inc a = 1 + a
```

Let's look at counter examples, where only one condition is fulfilled.

```
test2 : List Int -> List Int
test2 xs = map proxy xs
  where
    inc a = 1 + a
    proxy : Int -> Int
    proxy a = inc a
```

Here, `inc` does not appear on the right hand side, but could be determined to be `Int -> Int`.

```
test3 : List Int -> List Int
test3 xs = map (cast . inc . cast) xs
  where
    inc a = 1 + a
```

Next, `inc` appears on the right hand side, but the type cannot be determined (as it could be `Nat -> Nat`, `Int32 -> Int32`, …), and thus the type of `cast` can't either.

Both `test2` and `test3` compile only when given a type declaration to `inc`.